# Appending a GET-Variable to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

I'm creating a menu with the wp_nav_menu() function. Now I'd like to add a GET variable to the end of ever link in the menu, like this:
www.mysite.com/page/?variable=123

Is there any way I can do this when using wp_nav_menu?

Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `'wp_nav_menu_objects'`. You get an array as argument, a list of all items.

Pseudo-code, not tested:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpse_76401_filter' );

function wpse_76401_filter( $items )
{
    $out = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        if ( isset ( $item->url ) )
            $item->url = add_query_arg( 'variable', '123', $item->url )

        $out[] = $item;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and it does exactly what I need – perfect solution. Thanks a lot!